# Unable to refresh UITableView with modified data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a iPad app, using XCode 4.5, Storyboards, Core Data and iOS 6.  I select a row, make a change to the contents of the record (which is successful), but the row doesn't change.  I have tried to refresh the UITableView, but **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is never called.  I have searched SO and Google to no avail; I don't see what's wrong.  Can someone please tell me how to fix this? (with an explanation of what I'm doing wrong for the next time?)

Here is the pertinent code:

```
- (IBAction)btnModify:(UIButton *)sender {

    //NSLog(@"btnModify clicked");

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    //  find client by primary telephone number
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aClientPrimaryPhone ==[c] %@", cvPrimaryPhone.text];
    ClientInfo *clientDataFound = [ClientInfo MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];

    if(clientDataFound)  {
        clientDataFound.aClientName = cvCustName.text;  //  now start moving the data
        clientDataFound.aClientAddr1 = cvAddress1.text;
        clientDataFound.aClientAddr2 = cvAddress2.text;
        clientDataFound.aClientCity = cvContactCity.text;
        clientDataFound.aClientPostalCode = cvPostalCode.text;
        clientDataFound.aClientCellPhone = cvCellPhone.text;
        clientDataFound.aClientPrimaryPhone = cvPrimaryPhone.text;
        clientDataFound.aClientEMail = cvPersonalEmail.text;
        clientDataFound.aClientNotes = cvNotes.text;

        [localContext MR_saveNestedContexts];

        [self reloadClientList];
    }
}
-(void) reloadClientList  {

    //Init Array to hold TableView Data
    tableDataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [tableDataArray addObjectsFromArray:[ClientInfo findAll]];  //  Load

    [self.clientList reloadData];

}
```

and this is ClientInfo.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface ClientInfo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientAddr1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientAddr2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientCellPhone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientCity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientEMail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * aClientImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientNotes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientPostalCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aClientPrimaryPhone;
```

@end

Answer (score 1):

I found it... my "clientList" was NOT connected to the object... don't know how I missed that one!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons I can think of:

1. Your table view reference clientList is nil. (not connected)
2. Your table view's DataSource & Delegate is not set (Actually I'm not sure if it compiles when DataSource is not set)
3. Your table view is a subclass of `UITableView` and in that subclass `reloadData` method is overridden.